# Equivalent to Oracle NTH_VALUE function

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let us have the following data

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[LogTable] ([DateSent] [datetime] NULL) 
GO
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [IX_LogTable_DateSent] ON [dbo].[LogTable] ([DateSent] DESC) 
GO

INSERT INTO [LogTable]
SELECT TOP 500000 NULL, DATEADD(day, ( ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 65530 ), 0)
FROM sys.sysobjects
CROSS JOIN sys.all_columns
```

I would like to find the second and the third lowest value for each year in `DateSent`. Oracle offers the `NTH_VALUE` function for that, however, there is no such thing in SQL Server. I have created the following query

```
SELECT YEAR(datesent),   
(
    SELECT datesent
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT datesent, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY datesent) r
        FROM logtable
        WHERE YEAR(datesent) = YEAR(lt.datesent)
    ) logtable_ranked
    WHERE logtable_ranked.r = 2
) second_lowest_in_year,
(
    SELECT datesent
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT datesent, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY datesent) r
        FROM logtable
        WHERE YEAR(datesent) = YEAR(lt.datesent)
    ) logtable_ranked
    WHERE logtable_ranked.r = 3
) thirt_lowest_in_year
FROM logtable lt
GROUP BY YEAR(datesent)
```

which returns the correct result, but it takes more than 7s CPU time on my server. Moreover, time of this solution grows linearly with a number of NTH values I need.  Is there a better (faster and maybe more elegant) way to compute NTH_VALUE in SQL Server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `row_number()` and conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT YEAR(datesent),
       MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 1 THEN datesent END) AS datesent_1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 2 THEN datesent END) AS datesent_2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 3 THEN datesent END) AS datesent_3
FROM (SELECT datesent,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR(datesent) ORDER BY datesent) AS seqnum
      FROM LogTable lt
     ) lt
GROUP BY YEAR(datesent)
ORDER BY YEAR(datesent);
```

Comment: really nice one. take less than 2s of CPU time to execute.